# How to upgrade latest version of program?

Tags: apt, upgrade

I am a newer for using Ubuntu.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and try to upgrade libwind0-heimdal to 7.5.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.4 from 7.5.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3.
The system displys 7.5.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3 is latest version of libwind0-heimdal after I execute apt update and apt install libwind0-heimdal.
But the 7.5.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.4 is released in fact.
So why the latest version I can't build by using apt command?

Surely, I still can build latest version in aonther way such as manually install.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 or the 2018-April release, reaches the end of it's 5 years of *standard* support in April 2023; ie. next month.  You should instead be considering how to upgrade your system, or are you waiting for the *last* supported day next month?  *ESM or Pro support is available, but that just applies security patches to the existing packages where supported in deb format and not requiring conversion to snap for updates*

Comment: I do see ` libwind0-heimdal | 7.5.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.4                 | bionic-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` so I'd suggest running `sudo apt update` to update your software lists & read that output for clues..   ie. are there any missing lines, what mirror are you using? or using the main archive?  If using a mirror I'd check it's up-to-date, but we're limited to the detail you provided.  I'd plan your *release-upgrade* rather soon though

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for your reply. I just want to know if apt can upgrade program in this solution. The link you shared, I have saw it on last some days so apt command should delay the upgrade program until they will be stable. Can I understand in this way?

Comment: @guiverc I execute apt install after apt update so the list should newest.

Comment: See my last comment; ie. in your position I'd return to basics... ie. update your software lists (*you're getting outdated packages I agree which highlights either you've not updated your machines software lists OR you're using a mirror that needs changing*)...   You do this with `sudo apt update` & reading output from that command...   Look for warnings, errors OR just missing lines from that output; that's where I'd expect the problem to be shown; we can only help you if you provide that output; that's where I'd start.  If I saw nothing wrong there, I'd likely move to `apt-cache policy` ...

Comment: Once you've confirmed (using `sudo apt update` without errors or missing lines), then you can start to explore on specific packages, where I'd use `apt-cache policy libwind0-heimdal` ie. down to package level where it'll show where your *latest* package is available & where your machine will get it from..  This output will provide detail you can explore such as you're using an *outdated* mirror, though that detail can also be obtained via prior `sudo apt update` command & quick check online using https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors etc

Comment: I saw some programs remind to be upgrade after executing sudo apt update but not have libwind0-heimdal. 
I saw the Installed: 7.5.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3 and Candidate: 7.5.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3 after apt-cache policy libwind0-heimdal

Comment: If you didn't get a source in the `apt-cache policy` command in your output to examine, then your issue is the prior `sudo apt update` step & missing output there... ie. check your sources, as if you're using one of the *architectures* I listed in the comment with package name (& repo, ie. then you have no valid source for `bionic-updates`).  If you have additional input; edit your question & add it there; this is a Q&A site and not a forum  (comments are from readers to the Original Poster & will get removed once details/clarifications exist in question)